# How do I interpolate this matlab data column containing NaNs?

Tags: matlab, interpolation

So I have a data column "`trainData`" that looks like:

```
[
    Nan
    Nan
    Nan
    110
    NaN
    89
    Nan
    Nan
    123

and so on
]
```

I basically need to interpolate this so as to get a final matrix column as :

```
[
    0
    36.6
    73.2
    110
    99.5
    89
    101.3
    112.6
    123

and so on
]
```

Can anyone help me how to do so?

I tried doing `interpl(traindata)` but that either gives me some weird row of NaN's or doesn't work. Please help me out with this.

Comment: Actually this is not interpolation, as the starting point is missing you are actually extrapolating.

Comment: Hmm... we can assume the start point as zero in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
y = [NaN
     NaN
     NaN
     110
     NaN
     89
     NaN
     NaN
     123];
```

The following gets you very close (I think you made an arithmetic error actually, and this is what you want):

```
y(1) = 0; %//I'm assuming this from your result, you gave us no information about this.

xi = (1:length(y))'; %'//Now I'm assuming that each element of your y matrix is equally spaced
x = xi(~isnan(y)); %// Find the x values that correspond to the numerical values of y
yi = interp1(x, y(~isnan(y)), xi)

yi =

         0
   36.6667
   73.3333
  110.0000
   99.5000
   89.0000
  100.3333
  111.6667
  123.0000
```